# Is it safe to use the IDENTITY column to delete duplicates in a temporary table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

If I have a temp table like

```
CREATE TABLE #Person 
(
    [ID] int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [LastName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL
)
```

Let's say I do bulk inserts to populate the table with many persons. I then want to remove `FirstName` duplicates. So say my table has many people called `John` and I want to keep whichever John is last. Is it safe to do:

```
DELETE FROM #Person
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT MAX(ID) AS MaxId
                 FROM #Person
                 GROUP BY FirstName);
```

or could this result in more rows than intended to be deleted?

Comment: It would work, yes, though I wouldn't suggest that a person's name is a good way to denote a duplicate person. I know plenty of people with the same first name as me, and I even knew someone with the same Firstname, Last Name, DOB and postcode when I was a child.

Comment: regarding the deletion, it works. but there is a risk to put PK on the identity column. You cannot really tell if the duplicate issue is happening as it always gives you the unique number. And another risk is the PK value for the same record before and after deleting will change, if you are having a FK on this identity column, it will bring about a linkage issue. (assume you do not set identity insert property)

Comment: @Larnu "I even knew someone with the same Firstname, Last Name, DOB and postcode" - do tell? lol that has to be the mother of all coincidence! Just supports my request that everyone is issued with a guid at birth LOL

Comment: There's not really much to tell other than that, @DaleK . Our dentist used to have to have both our files when we visited (obviously not together) so that they could work out which one we were, as their late 80's system couldn't handle 2 people having the same details. :)